# Track multithreaded program execution using ASM Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to write a program that observes the execution of a simple multithreaded user program and returns a queue structure detailing the order in which the user program's threads worked through it. Each element of the returned queue should detail:

- thread id of the thread that undertook the work
- source file line number denoting the thread's position in the user code
- class name of the user code class in which the thread is executing

given the following user program:

```
public class UserCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                System.out.println("Hello again");
            }, String.valueOf(i));
            th.start();
            try {
                th.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One might expect a queue like so (where each element takes the form {thread id, line number, class name}):

```
(head)
[
    {1, 3, "UserCode"}, 
    {1, 4, "UserCode"}, 
    {1, 7, "UserCode"}, 
    {1, 8, "UserCode"}, 
    {24, 5, "UserCode"}, 
    ... , 
    {1, 15, "UserCode"}
]
(tail)
```

My approach thus far has been to instrument the user code using the ASM framework. I have the following premain:

```
public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer((new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                if (loader == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                /*
                ClassReader parses the compiled class given as a byte array, and calls the
                corresponding visit methods on the ClassVisitor instance passed as
                argument to its accept method. It can be seen as an event producer.
                 */
                ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);

                /*
                ClassWriter builds compiled classes directly in binary form. It produces as
                output a byte array containing the compiled class, which can be retrieved
                with the toByteArray method. It can be seen as an event consumer.
                 */
                ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

                /*
                ClassVisitor delegates all the method calls it receives to another
                ClassVisitor instance. It can be seen as an event filter.
                 */

                LineNumClassVisitor visitor = new LineNumClassVisitor(cw);

                cr.accept(visitor, 0);
                
                return cw.toByteArray();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

And the following custom ClassVisitor:

```
public final class LineNumClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    private Mediator mediator;
    private boolean isMediatorPresent;
    private boolean isStaticBlockPresent;

    public LineNumClassVisitor(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM9, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
                                     String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        return new LineNumMethodVisitor(super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions));
    }
}
```

...which makes use of the following MethodVisitor (indebted to suggested solution from this post: [ASM & Javaagent bytecode instrumentation: ClassFormatError: StackMapTable format error: bad offset for Uninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877465/asm-javaagent-bytecode-instrumentation-classformaterror-stackmaptable-format/72878984#72878984)):

```
public final class LineNumMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
    private int newLineNumber = -1;

    protected LineNumMethodVisitor(MethodVisitor mv){
        super(Opcodes.ASM9, mv);
    }

    private boolean setLineNumData() {
        int lineNumber = this.newLineNumber;
        if (lineNumber < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        this.newLineNumber = -1;

        super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
                "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        super.visitLdcInsn("line: " + lineNumber + " thread:");
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                "java/io/PrintStream", "print", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
                "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
                "java/lang/Thread", "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;", false);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                "java/lang/Thread", "getId", "()J", false);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(J)V", false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitInsn(opcode);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitIntInsn(int opcode, int operand) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitIntInsn(opcode, operand);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int varIndex) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitVarInsn(opcode, varIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitFieldInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor,
                                boolean isInterface) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInvokeDynamicInsn(String name, String descriptor, Handle bootstrapMethodHandle,
                                       Object... bootstrapMethodArguments) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(name, descriptor,
                bootstrapMethodHandle, bootstrapMethodArguments);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitJumpInsn(int opcode, Label label) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitJumpInsn(opcode, label);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLdcInsn(Object value) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitLdcInsn(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitIincInsn(int varIndex, int increment) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitIincInsn(varIndex, increment);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitTableSwitchInsn(int min, int max, Label dflt, Label... labels) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitTableSwitchInsn(min, max, dflt, labels);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLookupSwitchInsn(Label dflt, int[] keys, Label[] labels) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitLookupSwitchInsn(dflt, keys, labels);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMultiANewArrayInsn(String descriptor, int numDimensions) {
        setLineNumData();
        super.visitMultiANewArrayInsn(descriptor, numDimensions);
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitInsnAnnotation(int typeRef, TypePath tp, String desc,
                                                 boolean visible) {
        setLineNumData();
        return super.visitInsnAnnotation(typeRef, tp, desc, visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
        this.newLineNumber = line;
        super.visitLineNumber(line, start);
    }
}
```

The implementation I currently have for `setLineNumData` is simply a placeholder but what I really want to do there, is to find a way to create an entry in the thread data queue with **minimal** impact on the 'natural' execution of the user program threads. In this placeholder implementation, I am inserting a sizable amount of additional bytecode into the user program whenever an instruction of any sort is visited (which is clearly not suitable).

I'm wondering if anyone could give some advice as to a good way to record this information without affecting the user program's execution. I was thinking of using some sort of shared Mediator object that would mediate between user code and my program adding elements to the queue, operating in its own thread. I haven't yet found a practical way this could work though, nor am I of the mind that it's necessarily a good way to approach the problem.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: The entire idea of enforcing a total order for all threads’ actions, even in terms of line numbers, contradicts the goal of “minimal impact on the ‘natural’ execution”. The natural execution is neither, in line numbers nor a total order.

Comment: I don't follow your meaning @Holger, can you please describe in detail what you mean?

Comment: Take for example, the three lines `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` `variable++` `}`. The optimizer may replace the entire loop with a single `variable += 10`. By inserting whatever construct to report the “executed lines” you are actively preventing the optimization, forcing a behavior of “executing lines” which is far away from “natural execution”. That’s already intrusive for a single threaded program. But concurrent programming means, there is no (global) order unless you enforce it with a synchronizing action, which is known to be intrusive and expensive. That’s why we normally we avoid it.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Does this process of optimisation take place after compilation? Where could I found out more about it?

Comment: This is a runtime optimization. [This article](https://wiki.openjdk.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20415918#LoopoptimizationsinHotspotServerVMCompiler(C2)-LoopOptimizations) covers some of the possible loop optimizations, however, the details are not important. One thing you have to keep in mind, is that the optimized code at runtime does not have to resemble the source code actions, not even remotely, as long as the (sequential) perceivable outcome is the same. That’s why many strange results may occur when not synchronizing multi-threaded code correctly.

Comment: @Holger, thinking about it, so long as each user program thread is forced to work through unoptimised code (and of course that the code's effect is equivalent to some optimisation's effect), the resulting queue is still usable for my purposes. Any suggestions in response to my initial question, considering the active prevention of optimisation as acceptable?

Comment: Well if you drop the “minimal impact” requirement, your existing code is already good enough.

Comment: @Holger, thanks. I think what I'm trying to get at is, I'm inserting 7 lines of bytecode for each instruction in order to print out source line number and thread id and am assuming this is relatively expensive. I'm trying to get to a minimally disruptive approach for creating a queue containing this information (or even, whether there is some alternative way of going about this where I don't even add to the bytecode at all. Maybe using some observer object that runs in its own thread and is signalled to whenever a specific label is being executed?..).